# To store value of a table variable into a variable of my own in selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

Hi i am using selenium with testng and right now i have to store a value present in the page to some variable but i am having much problem regarding this

This is the main part of the page source where i need to store the value "2" in some variable.
I don't understand whether non-truncated-text will give me the value because their are too many such same lines are their with different values.

here is my page source .

< non-truncated-text="2">

Answer (score 0):

You can use `storeTable ( tableCellAddress, variableName )` to get text from a table. Selenium has many store functions to store values on the page into variables. See [Selenium Reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) for a list of functions.